# Angular 2 Reference Google Maps Type Definition

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use The Definitely Typed Angular 2 typings file in my angular 2.

I have the following at the top of my component.

```
/// <reference path="libs/angular2-google-maps/google.maps.d.ts"/>
```

Which is the correct route to the file.
But further down the file I have things like

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle(<any>{
...
```

And it's giving me errors on compiling saying

`.....component.ts(56,24): error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'google'.`

This had been allowing me to ignore the typescript errors 5 minutes ago and run my project anyway, and the google maps worked fine. But now (6pm friday of course) I can't get the project to build.

Can anybody suggest a fix or a workaround?
I will happily ignore this typescript error until Monday if anybody can tell me how?